# Last member of my dict is deleted in for iterator

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

I'm a beginner. I built a dictionary and a dataframe. I try to update my dataframe in a loop with the
values of a dictionary. I do that in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame(index= ["nima", "niloo", "javad", "zahra"], columns= np.arange(1,1001))
inp = {"name":"", "night":"", "what":"", "price": 1000}

for keys in list(inp.keys()):
  print("please Enter", keys, ":")
  inp[keys] =  input()
  a.loc[inp.pop('name')][inp.pop('night')] = inp.pop("price")
```

when I run this
First: it asks the 'name'
Second: it asks the 'night'
and then it returns the error:  KeyError: 'price'

By printing the dictionary, I find that after running `for` it deletes the last member "price"
but I don't know why!

plz help me

Comment: You're popping in the loop. The first iteration will pop `"price"` from `inp`, then it won't be in the dictionary on the next iteration.

Comment: You probably want `.get()` instead of `.pop()`

Comment: BTW, normally you put the input prompt in the argument to `input()`, not as a separate `print()` statement.

Comment: The dataframe update should probably be *after* the loop that fills in the dictionary.

Comment: Dear @Barmar I didn't use `input()` because it only takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments and I had more

Comment: Use concatenation or formatting: `input(f"please enter {keys}:")`

Comment: Nice, Thanks @Barmar